# Understanding how many times the jquery events are called and right handling of keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop my webpage where I have a simple input field where I can type something. I want that when I type something and press "enter", a function gets called. The code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBar").click(function(){
        $("#searchBar").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).trigger("enterKey");
            }
        });
        $("#searchBar").bind("enterKey", function (e) {
            searchFunction();
        });
    })
})
```

Something is not working well. I have 2 questions:

1. First of all by debugging on the browser I realize that the event "keyup" is called whenever I type any kind of character, but not when I press "enter" and I don't know why.
2. By always debugging and using a breakpoint on the keyup handler, it happens that when I press a key, in order to get out from the breakpoint I have to resume the script execution once.. then if I type another character and I go again at the breakpoint, I have to resume the script exectuion twice instead of once to continue debugging.. and so on incresing.. why do I have this kind of behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are attaching a new `keyup` and `enterKey` event at each `click` on element. What is purpose of `click` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. #searchBar only listens to keyUp and Enter if you have clicked on it at least once
2. #searchBar adds a new keyUp and Enter listener for each time it receives a click event

I'd just bind the events once like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBar").keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
        }
    });
    $("#searchBar").bind("enterKey", function (e) {
        searchFunction();
    });
});
```

I can't come up with a valid reason to stop listening to the events, but if that's what you want, then I'd unbind just before or after the call to your searchFunction();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBar").click(function(e){
        $(this).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
               $(this).trigger("enterKey");
            }
        });
        $(this).bind("enterKey", function (e) {
            searchFunction();
            $(this).unbind("enterKey");
            $(this).unbind("keyup");
        });
    });
    // but you'd also need to unbind the events if the user clicks somewhere else in the document, otherwise, these events would still get attached every time the user clicks #searchBar
});
```

But it's unnecessary, as the events are only fired when #searchBar has focus. All these events also detach if you delete #searchBar

Also, why fire "enterKey" when you already are listening for keystrokes?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchBar").keyup(function (event) {
        var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which; //this for cross-browser compatibility
        if (keycode == 13) {
            searchFunction();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: okey.. I got the last option and it's the one I like the most.. but there is still one problem. If I debug, every key fires the keyup event except when I press insert

Comment: my fault.. the searchbox was in a form.. and pressing Enter in a form prevented the event from being handled

Comment: Glad you found the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have to resume the script exectuion twice instead of once to
>   continue debugging.. and so on incresing.. why do I have this kind of
>   behavior?

You are attaching a new `keyup` and `enterKey` event at each click on element.

Remove `click` event or use `.one()` to attach `click` event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var search = $("#searchBar").keyup(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       search.trigger("enterKey");
     }
  })
  .on("enterKey", function (e) {
    searchFunction();
  });        
})
```

or, if one `click` is intended to begin process

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var search = $("#searchBar").one("click", function() { 
    search.keyup(function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        search.trigger("enterKey");
      }
    })
    .on("enterKey", function (e) {
      searchFunction();
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: I understood the problem and the **.one()** probably gets closer to what I want. But there is still something.. what I want to achieve is: I have a box where I can insert a text.. if I click on the box, insert the text and click insert, I have to use the method searchFunction();. Instead, if I click on the box, insert a text and then click somewhere else out of the box, I don't want to use the function even if I click on Insert